# Filtering for items in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, filter, listener, actionlistener

I have a package, called Things. In this package, there are regular and abstract classes such as Fruit, Food, Perishable, Shoes, Item etc. I want to create a filter that would filter these when clicked on. For example, clicking on the button fruit would filer for fruits. In a separate package called CODE, I have 4 classes, each serving a function such as importing my data and methods, running the app, the GUI and the controller. I've set up the GUI class to show the button, however, I am confused on how to get Java to filter my items in the "listening" class - a class which responds to the buttons clicked in the GUI class. How do I approach writing the code? I have tried the following, but it doesn't work. Do I have to import things.food in the code?

In another post there was this code:

```
List<Person> beerDrinkers = persons.stream()
.filter(p -> p.getAge() > 16).collect(Collectors.toList());

//Lets say I edit this to make it similar to my problem
List<Item> Perishables = Food.stream()
.filter(p -> p.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That would not work, and it gives me errors. Could someone explain how this code works and how I could apply it to my problem?

```
// I currently have this empty in my controller class to use as a filter. Am I suppose to filter over here or in the class that holds the methods?
else if(text.equals("Food")){
    }
```

package Products;
    public abstract class Food extends Item {

```
String Expiration_Date;

public String toString()
{
    return super.toString() + ", Expiration: " + Expiration_Date;
}
}

package Products;

public class Fruit extends Perishable {

public Fruit(String s)
{
    StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(s);

    stk.nextToken();

    this.Item_name = stk.nextToken();
    this.Item_code = stk.nextToken();
    this.price = Double.parseDouble(stk.nextToken());
    this.Expiration_Date = stk.nextToken();
    if (stk.nextToken().compareTo("false") == 0)
        this.flag = false;
    else
        this.flag = true;
    this.inventory = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());

}

public String toString()
{
    return super.toString();
}

}
```

Comment: there is one thing which brought my atention, you have code : filter(p -> p.getName()) . function passed to filter should returns bolean value, function name getName which returns value used by filter, suggest return won't be boolean.

Comment: by addition, could you add errors which you are getting? that could clear some issues

Answer (score -1):

The code that you referred to is using JDK 1.8. 
You should check your jdk version by executing 
`javac -version` in the console.

```
List<Item> foods = perishables.stream()
.filter(p -> p.getSimpleName().equals("Food")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Referring to the source, Food is a list for Item? List.stream() returns Stream interface with the collection. Stream is a interface of JDK 1.8 that we can create a closure to operate the collection element. You should return a bool value in the filter method.

[stream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream-) is a method of class that implements **Collection**, so we use this method of an ArrayList(or others) of Perishable to get **Stream** interface with Perishable objects. Then use filter method to [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) Perishable objects and return a new stream with filtered objects. Finally using collect(Collectors.toList()) to accumulate filtered objects to an ArrayList.

BTW Class.getSimpleName can return a short class name without package names.

Comment: how would I go about tackling this problem then? I assume I have the latest version of JDk as im using the new os for mac.

Comment: Hi, I've attached how those classes look like, I'm not great with terminology.

Comment: I think you'd better check that jdk version because in most cases we won't install that. Stream with lamdba can **only** used in thta version. If the jdk is older than that, you can install one more jdk and set specific compiler in your IDE.[JDK1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)